# No variable substitution with a call command

Tags: gnuplot

I have a gnuplot script (template) which looks like this (a little bit shortened):

```
#!/bin/bash
F1=file_1
F2=file_2    
pdffile=output.pdf
#
term="terminal pdfcairo enhanced fontscale .3 lw 3" 
out="output '$pdffile'"
#
gnuplot -persist << EOF 
#
set $term
set $out
#
call "statistic-file.txt"  
#
#  ... (some formating instructions removed) 
#
plot  "$F1"  w l lt 1 lc rgb "red"   t "Graph1" ,\
      "$F2"  w l lt 1 lc rgb "green" t "Graph2"        
EOF
okular $pdffile
```

F1 F2 are variables for my data files. Via "call" command i try to include "statistic-file.txt" in which the variables F1 F2 are also used. This file looks like this (also shortened):

```
#
stats "$F1" u 2 nooutput name "Y1_"
stats "$F1" u 1 every ::Y1_index_min::Y1_index_min nooutput
X1_min = STATS_min
stats "$F1" u 1 every ::Y1_index_max::Y1_index_max nooutput
X1_max = STATS_max
#
# etc 
#
 set label  \
      front center point pt 6 lc rgb "red" ps 1.0 \
      at first X1_max,Y1_max tc rgb "red" \
      sprintf("%.0f kW / %.0f°", Y1_max, X1_max)
```

Executing the script, i get a error message:

```
"statistic-file.txt", line 2: Invalid substitution $F
```

Pasting the content of "statistic-file.txt" into the template file, then it works. It looks as if the variables in the second file have no relation to the variables in the template file. I prefer the 2 files solution, but how to solve it? Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing bash variables and gnuplot variables. `$F1` is a bash variable and will be substituted by bash only within your bash script. Within "statistic-file.txt", bash substitutes nothing, and gnuplot complains about the unknown `$F1`.

You can try to "convert" the bash variable `$F1` into a gnuplot variable `datafile1` like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

F1="file_1"

gnuplot -persist << EOF 

datafile1="$F1"
call "statistic-file.txt"
plot datafile1 w lp

EOF
```

with the following statistic-file.txt:

```
stats datafile1
```

Then bash replaces `$F1` with the respective filename and gnuplot uses its own variable `datafile1`, even within the subsequently called "statistic-file.txt".

Just for completeness: The error message "Invalid substitution $F" comes from gnuplot 4, gnuplot 5 complains about "no datablock named $F1".

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be probably to just move the definition of those variables into the Gnuplot template which is being generated and use them directly, i.e.,

```
#!/bin/bash

pdffile=output.pdf
#
term="terminal pdfcairo enhanced fontscale .3 lw 3" 
out="output '$pdffile'"
#
gnuplot -persist << EOF 
#
F1="file_1"
F2="file_2"
set $term
set $out
#
call "statistic-file.txt"  
#
#  ... (some formating instructions removed) 
#
plot  F1  w l lt 1 lc rgb "red"   t "Graph1" ,\
      F2  w l lt 1 lc rgb "green" t "Graph2"        
EOF
```

Similar changes would be necessary also in the file `statistic-file.txt`, e.g., `stats F1 u 2 nooutput name "Y1_"` instead of `stats "$F1" u 2 nooutput name "Y1_"`.

Comment: You got there first :)